# Connecting to Spark cluster remotely

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

I am trying to connect to the spark master node(remote cluster node) from my local system using a Java program. I am using the following API to connect:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WorkCountApp").setMaster("spark://masterIP:7077");
 JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

My program tries to connect to the master but fails after some time. Below is the stacktrace:

```
  16/11/30 17:40:26 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ec2-54-202-212-141.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7077/user/Master...
    16/11/30 17:40:46 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
    16/11/30 17:40:46 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
    16/11/30 17:40:46 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.31.11.1:4040
    16/11/30 17:40:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
    16/11/30 17:40:46 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
    16/11/30 17:40:46 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
    16/11/30 17:40:46 ERROR OneForOneStrategy: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:103)
```

Please help me with the same

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for a connection fail. However for this, it looks like there are no worker threads that have been instantiated for this Spark master.

On the remote machine you need to start spark master as well as spark worker (slave)